# pthread and the right way to invoke many threads

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have this code

My scope was: the program creates MAX_THREAD threads, three in this case, each thread prints Thread-ID and exits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX_THREAD 3

void *thr_func(void *arg);

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thr[MAX_THREAD];
    int i, thr_err;

    /* I expected three threads ... but there is only one */
    for (i=0; i<MAX_THREAD; i++) {

        printf("thread %d: - ", i);

        if ((thr_err = pthread_create(&thr[i],NULL, thr_func, NULL)) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Err. pthread_create() %s\n", strerror(thr_err));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (pthread_join(thr[i], NULL) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Err. pthread_join() %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *thr_func(void *arg)
{
    pthread_t tid = pthread_self();
    printf("TID %lu - Address 0x%x\n", tid, (unsigned int)pthread_self());

    pthread_exit((void*)0);
}
```

output is:

```
thread 0: - TID 3075976048 - Address 0xb757ab70
thread 1: - TID 3075976048 - Address 0xb757ab70
thread 2: - TID 3075976048 - Address 0xb757ab70
```

I don't understand why there is only one thread!

I have a doubt on this declaration:

```
 pthread_t thr[MAX_THREAD];
```

Can i create an array of three threads or this is only one thread ????

**SOLVED**

New code (I've just put pthread_joiun() outside of for loop)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

#define MAX_THREAD 3

void *thr_func(void *thr_num);

int main(void) {
    pthread_t thr[MAX_THREAD];
    int i, thr_err;

    for (i=0; i<MAX_THREAD; i++) {

        if ((thr_err = pthread_create(&thr[i],NULL, thr_func, (void*)i)) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Err. pthread_create() %s\n", strerror(thr_err));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<MAX_THREAD; i++) {
        if (pthread_join(thr[i], NULL) != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Err. pthread_join() %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *thr_func(void *thr_num)
{
    pthread_t tid;

    if ((tid = syscall(SYS_gettid)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Err. syscall() %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("thread '%d' - TID %lu - Address 0x%x\n",
            (int)thr_num, tid, (unsigned int)tid);

    pthread_exit((void*)0);
}
```

Output is:

```
thread '1' - TID 8780 - Address 0x224c
thread '0' - TID 8779 - Address 0x224b
thread '2' - TID 8781 - Address 0x224d
```

Addresses and thread-ID now are different.

Comment: Note that your code isn't portable. The results of casting a `pthread_t` to an `unsigned int` are totally unpredictable. (On some platforms, you might have two threads with different IDs but that appear the same when cast to an `unsigned int`. The same thread might even have more than one such result, so unequal values don't even prove different threads. That's why you need `pthread_equal`.)

Comment: Yes I know about that, this is only for testing thread invocations, my next code will be with syscall(SYS_gettid) to manage TIDs. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely getting the same TID and address precisely because you `pthread_join()` each thread before starting the next one. The `pthreads` library seems to be a bit lazy about reclaiming the associated data structures (probably for efficiency), so the next thread you spawn just uses the same data structures the previous one did. Try writing two loops, one to create the threads, then another one to do the `pthread_join()`s after all the threads have been created.

Comment: Many thanks, with pthread_join() outside of the for loop works well.

Answer (score 0):

One immediate problem that leapt out at me was the use of for (i=1; i<=MAX_THREAD; i++) in your loop. Your data structure (pthread_t thr[MAX_THREAD]) is 0-indexed. It might therefore be simplest to run your loop as for (i=0; i

Nothing else *appears* broken. Your code is odd because you are launching each thread (from the thread executing main) and then blocking on its completion via pthread_join before you proceed to fork off the next thread.

This does not explain why your output shows "thread 0:" each time ... I would expect to see this starting with 1 in your current program and also get incremented "i" gets incremented in your loop. What does your code print if you don't do the pthread spawning and joining? After you fix the loop bound as indicated above, does it output "thread 0: thread 1: thread 2:"

Comment: the problem is not thread 1,2, etc... the problem is the same TID and same address.

Comment: Ok now I understand! the code now is correct but the problem is still here.

Comment: why TIDs are equals? Why addresses are equals? This is that I don't understand.

Comment: After you fixed the loop bounds, can you cut and paste the program output?

Comment: My program output is the output in my first post.

Answer (score 0):

I think, before starting new thread, old thread is getting exited and hence the new thread is getting the same TID. Try open new thread by keeping the old thread alive, I believe it will will give different TID.